# HeaderListView with Horizontal Scrolling Header

Tags: java, android, listview, scroll, header

I'm looking for a HeaderListView like this one: http://applidium.github.io/HeaderListView/ but instead have a header that has a horizontal scrolling ability that lists categories of my list view, like in uber eats where it comes up with stuff like:
Drinks

Coke

Sprite

Pizza

Pepperoni Pizza

Cheese Pizza

In the header it will have tabs:
Drinks Pizza

If you're viewing the drinks, Drinks will be underlined, pizza will not be underlined. If you're viewing the pizza, Pizza will be underlined, drinks will not be underlined,. You can scroll down the menu to see what you want. Can someone direct me to where it is? I need something in java please.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. This is a compilation of recycler view item move, 2 different types of items in one recycler view and navigating through recycler views like uber eats.

In a public class YourNameOfFragment extends Fragment. I put this in the onCreateView method

```
    RecyclerView recyclerViewItem;
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;
    TabLayout tabLayout;
    List<String> list;
    View root;
//You need to have an empty tablayout and a recyclerview in your layout
    root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_your_name_of, container, false);
    recyclerViewItem = root.findViewById(R.id.linear_recyclerview);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        tabLayout = root.findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);

//Set up smooth scroller to set scroll position in recycler view
    LinearSmoothScroller smoothScroller=new LinearSmoothScroller(getActivity()){
            @Override
            protected int getVerticalSnapPreference() {
                return LinearSmoothScroller.SNAP_TO_START;
            }
        };

//Setup items and tabs
    List<FoodItem> items = new ArrayList<FoodItem>();
        list = new ArrayList<String>();
        items.add(new Header("Header 1"));
        TabLayout.Tab tab1 = tabLayout.newTab();
        tab1.setText(items.get(items.size()-1));
        list.add((String)tab1.getText());
        tabLayout.addTab(tab1);
        items.add(new Item("Text 1", "Rabble rabble"));
        items.add(new Item("Text 2", "Rabble rabble"));
        items.add(new Item("Text 3", "Rabble rabble"));
        items.add(new Item("Text 4", "Rabble rabble"));
        items.add(new Item("Text 5", "Rabble rabble"));
        items.add(new Item("Text 6", "Rabble rabble"));
        items.add(new Item("Text 7", "Rabble rabble"));
        items.add(new Item("Text 8", "Rabble rabble"));

        items.add(new Header("Header 2"));
        TabLayout.Tab tab2 = tabLayout.newTab();
        list.add((String)tab2.getText());
        tab2.setText(items.get(items.size()-1).getStr1());
        tabLayout.addTab(tab2);

        items.add(new Item("Text 5", "Rabble rabble"));
        items.add(new Item("Text 6", "Rabble rabble"));
        items.add(new Item("Text 7", "Rabble rabble"));
        items.add(new Item("Text 8", "Rabble rabble"));
        items.add(new Item("Text 5", "Rabble rabble"));
        items.add(new Item("Text 6", "Rabble rabble"));
        items.add(new Item("Text 7", "Rabble rabble"));
        items.add(new Item("Text 8", "Rabble rabble"));
        items.add(new Item("Text 5", "Rabble rabble"));
        items.add(new Item("Text 6", "Rabble rabble"));
        items.add(new Item("Text 7", "Rabble rabble"));
        items.add(new Item("Text 8", "Rabble rabble"));

        TwoTextArrayAdapter adapter = new TwoTextArrayAdapter(getContext(), items);
        recyclerViewItem.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerViewItem.setAdapter(adapter);
//Setup the recycler view to be able to move items
        ItemTouchHelper.Callback callback = new ItemMoveCallback(adapter);
        ItemTouchHelper touchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(callback);
        touchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerViewItem);

    recyclerViewItem.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
               // Toast.makeText(this, "You clicked " + adapter.getItem(position) + " on row number " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                int position = ((LinearLayoutManager)recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
                if(dy > 0)
                {//when it scrolls one direction, do this
                    if(adapter.getItem(position).getType() == FoodItem.TYPE_HEADER) {
                        String item1 = adapter.getItem(position).getStr1();
                        String item2;
                        for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
                            item2 = (String) (tabLayout.getTabAt(i).getText());
                            if (item1.equals(item2)) {
                                tabAutoSelected = 1;
                                tabLayout.selectTab(tabLayout.getTabAt(i));
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else {//when it scrolls, the other direction, do this
                    String header = "";
                    for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getItemCount(); i++) {
                        if (adapter.getItem(i).getType() == FoodItem.TYPE_HEADER) {
                            header = adapter.getItem(i).getStr1();
                        }
                        if (i == position) {
                            String item2;
                            for (int y = 0; y < tabLayout.getTabCount(); y++) {
                                item2 = (String) (tabLayout.getTabAt(y).getText());
                                if (header.equals(item2)) {
                                    tabAutoSelected = 1;
                                    tabLayout.selectTab(tabLayout.getTabAt(y));
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });


//tabLayout listener so that you can click on tabs and it takes you to where you want to go
    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                if(tabAutoSelected == 1)//if tab is selected by scrolling, then reset flag
                {
                    tabAutoSelected = 0;
                }
                else{//if tab is selected by clicking then set recycler view to header
                    for(int y = 0; y < adapter.getItemCount(); y++)
                    {

                        String item1 = adapter.getItem(y).getStr1();
                        String item2 = (String)tab.getText();
                        if(item1.equals(item2))
                        {
                            smoothScroller.setTargetPosition(y);
                            recyclerViewItem.getLayoutManager().startSmoothScroll(smoothScroller);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                if(tabAutoSelected == 1)//if tab is selected by the scrolling, then reset flag
                {
                    tabAutoSelected = 0;
                }
                else{//if tab is selected by clicking, then scroll recycler view to header
                    for(int y = 0; y < adapter.getItemCount(); y++)
                    {

                        String item1 = adapter.getItem(y).getStr1();
                        String item2 = (String)tab.getText();
                        if(item1.equals(item2))
                        {
                            smoothScroller.setTargetPosition(y);
                            recyclerViewItem.getLayoutManager().startSmoothScroll(smoothScroller);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        });

    return root;
```

FoodItem.java

```
public interface FoodItem {
    int TYPE_HEADER = 100;
    int TYPE_ITEM = 101;

    int getType();
    String getStr1();
}
```

Header.java

```
public class Header implements FoodItem {
    // variables and methods
    public String str1;

    @Override
    public int getType() {
        return FoodItem.TYPE_HEADER;
    }

    public Header(String text1) {
        super();
        this.str1 = text1;
    }

    public String getStr1() {
        return str1;
    }

    public void setStr1(String str1) {
        this.str1 = str1;
    }
}
```

Item.java

```
public class Item implements FoodItem {
    // variables and methods
    public String str1;
    public String str2;

    @Override
    public int getType() {
        return FoodItem.TYPE_ITEM;
    }

    public Item(String text1, String text2) {
        super();
        this.str1 = text1;
        this.str2 = text2;
    }

    public String getStr1() {
        return str1;
    }

    public void setStr1(String str1) {
        this.str1 = str1;
    }

    public String getStr2() {
        return str2;
    }

    public void setStr2(String str2) {
        this.str2 = str2;
    }
}
```

TwoTextArrayAdapter.java

```
public class TwoTextArrayAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter implements ItemTouchHelperAdapter {
    private List<FoodItem> list;

    public TwoTextArrayAdapter(Context context, List<FoodItem> itemViewHolders) {
        list = itemViewHolders;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView;
        switch (viewType) {
            case FoodItem.TYPE_ITEM:
                itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.my_list_item, parent, false);
                return new ItemViewHolder(itemView);
            case FoodItem.TYPE_HEADER:
                itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.header, parent, false);
                return new HeaderViewHolder(itemView);
            default: 
                return null;
        }
    }

    public FoodItem getItem(int id) {
        return list.get(id);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        switch (getItemViewType(position)) {
            case FoodItem.TYPE_ITEM:
                ((ItemViewHolder) holder).bindView(position);
                break;
            case FoodItem.TYPE_HEADER:
                ((HeaderViewHolder) holder).bindView(position);
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return list.get(position).getType();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (list == null) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return list.size();
        }
    }

    public void setFoodList(List<? extends FoodItem> FoodList) {
        if (list == null){
            list = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        list.clear();
        list.addAll(list);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements ItemTouchHelperViewHolder {
        public  View view;
        public TextView txtViewItem, txtViewItem2;

        public ItemViewHolder(@NonNull android.view.View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            txtViewItem = itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_content1);
            txtViewItem2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_content2);
            view = itemView;
        }

        void bindView(int position) {
            Item item = (Item) list.get(position);
            // bind data to the views
            // textView.setText()...
            txtViewItem.setText(item.getStr1());
            txtViewItem2.setText(item.getStr2());
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected() {
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemClear() {
            view.setBackgroundColor(0);
        }
    }

    public class HeaderViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements ItemTouchHelperViewHolder{
        public  View view;
        public TextView txtViewSeparator;


        public HeaderViewHolder(@NonNull android.view.View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            txtViewSeparator = itemView.findViewById(R.id.separator);
            view = itemView;

        }
        void bindView(int position) {
            Header header = (Header) list.get(position);
            // bind data to the views
            // textView.setText()...
            txtViewSeparator.setText(header.getStr1());
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected() {
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemClear() {
            view.setBackgroundColor(0);
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onItemDismiss(int position) {
        list.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onItemMove(int fromPosition, int toPosition) {
        //Log.v("", "Log position" + fromPosition + " " + toPosition);
        if (fromPosition < list.size() && toPosition < list.size()) {
            if (fromPosition < toPosition) {
                for (int i = fromPosition; i < toPosition; i++) {
                    Collections.swap(list, i, i + 1);
                }
            } else {
                for (int i = fromPosition; i > toPosition; i--) {
                    Collections.swap(list, i, i - 1);
                }
            }
            notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```